# See file metadata from NERDTree

Tags: vim, ls, nerdtree

[nerdtree](/questions/tagged/nerdtree) allows navigation through the file system within [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) and performing file system operation like creating and deleting files and directories.

Is there any command to see file metadata like timestamp, owner or permissions, as a unix `ls -l` command would output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in (as NERDTree is mainly a file explorer for locating and opening files within Vim, this isn't a typical use case), but you can surely build something like that through the plugin's extension points.

`:help NERDTreeAPI` documents how to define custom key mappings and menu items. As these get passed the current tree object, you can then query and display the metadata, e.g. using

```
let metadata = system('ls -l ' . shellescape(filespec))
```

Comment: Thanks. In case you are interested I just created the option and submitted a PR https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/pull/376

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! Why have you omitted the `shellescape()` in your patch, though?!

Comment: `shellescape()` was omitted because I forgot to. I already corrected the PR. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

This is an explicit answer.  You can find the answer if you dig into the comments from Ingo Karkat's answer.

1. Open Nerdtree
2. Move to the specific file or directory
3. Press the keys **m** and **l**

[image]

92 represents the filesize in bytes.